# Echo The Values Of Query

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, echo

I want to save the number of likes (`likes`) in a variable (`$likes`) and print it in a status post (`$statuslist`) and if it's possible without a `foreach` loop beacuse I cannot put the `$statuslist` inside the loop as I tried.
But the code only works partly. It echos the number of likes, but only when **EVERY** status post gets 0,1,2,3 etc. likes. And I do not want this. I want to echo the number of likes on **EACH** posts apart from the others.
For this a `foreach` loop and a `fetch_object` would work fine, but if I would use `foreach` loop I had to put `$statuslist` inside it and I do not want that.
So is there any solutions?

Mysql:

```
$statusQuery = $conn->query("
        SELECT 
        status.id,
        COUNT(status_likes.id) AS likes,
        GROUP_CONCAT(users.username SEPARATOR '|') AS liked_by
        FROM status

        LEFT JOIN status_likes
        ON status.id = status_likes.status

        LEFT JOIN users
        ON status_likes.user = users.id

        GROUP BY status.id 
    ");

    $likes = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statusQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
        $likes = $row["likes"];
    }
```

Status Post:

```
$statuslist .= '<div id="status_'.$statusid.'" class="status_boxes">';
$statuslist .= '<div>'.$statusDeleteButton.'<p id="status_date">';
$statuslist .= '<b>Post: </b>'.$postdate.'</p>'.$user_image.';
$statuslist .= '<p id="status_text">'.$data.'</p>';
$statuslist .= '.$shareButton.''.$likeButton.''.$likes.' people like it.
$statuslist .= '</div>'.$status_replies.'</div>';
```

**EDIT:**
I have already tried it and worked, but I could not save the number of likes into a varable and echo it in the `$statuslist`.

```
while($row = $statusQuery -> fetch_object()){
        $statuses[] = $row;
    }

foreach ($statuses as $status) {
    echo $status->likes;
}
```

Comment: You don't do anything with `$likes` inside the loop, and its overwritten each iteration. And you have a syntax error in the "status post" code. See the highlighting.

Comment: Yes, I edited in the text editor of this webiste but in my text editor I have no syntax errors. And what should I do with the `$likes` variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
require("MyPost.php"); // Needs to be at the top of the script!!

$statusQuery = $conn->query("
    SELECT 
    status.id,
    COUNT(status_likes.id) AS likes,
    GROUP_CONCAT(users.username SEPARATOR '|') AS liked_by
    FROM status

    LEFT JOIN status_likes
    ON status.id = status_likes.status

    LEFT JOIN users
    ON status_likes.user = users.id

    GROUP BY status.id 
");

$posts = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($statusQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

    $mypost = new MyPost($row);
    array_push($posts, $mypost);

}


foreach ($posts as $key => $post_value) {
    // echo $post_value->id
    echo $post_value->display_post();
}
```

Create a new file by the *MyPost.php* and put it in the same folder as your script. 
The contents of *MyPost.php* needs to be the below code.

```
class MyPost
{

    // You can change these to private if you would like (change public to private)
    public $statusDeleteButton = "DELETE_BUTTON_HERE";
    public $likeButton = "LIKE_BUTTON_HERE";
    public $shareButton = "LIKE_BUTTON_HERE";


    // Keep public
    public $id, $postdate, $user_image, $liked_by, $likes, $data, $status_replies;

    // Code that is ran when a new MyPost object is created.
    public function __construct($array)
    {
        // I am assuming you are getting these from the sql also? 
        //If you are then you can delete these variables.
        $this->user_image = "";
        $this->postdate = "";
        $this->status_replies = "";
        $this->data = "";

        // Set the variables (Don't delete)
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
            $this->$key = $value;
        }
    }

    // Return the string for the post.
    public function display_post()
    {
       return '<div id="status_'.$this->id.'" class="status_boxes">
            <div>'.$this->statusDeleteButton.'<p id="status_date">
                <b>Post: </b>'.$this->postdate.'</p>'.$this->user_image.
                '<p id="status_text">'.$this->data.'</p>'.
                $this->shareButton.''.$this->likeButton.''.$this->likes.' people like it.
        </div>'.$this->status_replies.'</div>';
    }
}
```